Inconsistency Principle in Coq
In a consistent system like Coq, it should never be possible to derive False.
However, I would like to show that any case where False is provable (even conditionally) leads to an overall inconsistency in the system.
Or, in other words, can we state the following?
(exists (P : Prop), P -> False) -> False

This property would allow the following sort of reasoning:
Section test.
Variable a : bool.
Context {H : if a then True else False}.
Goal False.
  assert (C : (exists (P : Prop), P -> False) -> False); [ admit | ].
  apply C; clear C.
  exists (a = false); intros.
  destruct a; auto.
Admitted.
End test.


You can state that, yes. You can't prove it, because it's false (there exists a proposition that implies False, namely False).

Your made a logical error. False is provable conditionally, namely under the condition that False holds, but this fact does not lead to an overall inconsistency. (I made much worse errors, one where I confounded $A \Rightarrow B$ and $B \Rightarrow A$ cost me attendance at the Math Olimpyad.)

Also, of course axioms in Coq can make a theory inconsistent, e.g. we can just issue an Axiom f : False., then False is provable.

I would like to show that any case where False is provable (even conditionally) leads to an overall inconsistency in the system.

Trying a literal translation, by the Curry-Howard correspondence, "False is provable" translates to 'False is inhabited', and "an overall inconsistency" is when 'False is derivable'.
So, your statement translates to 'if False is inhabited, we can derive False':
Theorem ex_falso :
  inhabited False -> False.
Proof. intros [f]. tauto. Qed.

Or, even more directly, 'given any inhabitant of False, we can derive False':
Theorem ex_falso' :
  forall (f : False), False.
Proof. tauto. Qed.

Which eventually boils down to simply the theorem False -> False.
P.S.  I have in fact played blind to the "(even conditionally)" part of your statement, as I didn't know how to succinctly put it, plus False -> False implicitly seemed to already capture the bottom line. But, inspired by Andrej Bauer's comment:
Indeed, False -> False is of course a theorem and a provable one in Coq, and does not per se lead to any inconsistency, we can in fact disprove (False -> False) -> False.
Goal ((False -> False) -> False) -> False.
Proof. tauto. Qed.

We can do even better, we can prove that any P : Prop such that P -> False must be equivalent to False, i.e. what I'd read "False and only False implies False":
Goal forall (P : Prop),
  (P -> False) -> (P <-> False).
Proof. tauto. Qed.


Consistency of Coq can only be proven externally (and established relatively to a stricly stronger metatheory otherwise Gödel's incompleteness theorem applies). That said, barring any implementation bug and additional axioms over Coq's logic, you should not be able to derive a closed term of type False in Coq. But this also means that you won't be able to prove the assertion
(exists (P : Prop), P -> False) -> False

because its premise is provable:
Goal exists P : Prop, P -> False.
Proof.
  exists False; trivial.
Qed.


There is a way to prove False in Coq, but in order to do so, you need to turn on program options that are known to lead to inconsistency.
From Coq Require Import Hurkens.
Unset Universe Checking.
Definition Hurkens'_paradox := PropNeqType.paradox eq_refl : False.

If you then Print Assumptions Hurkens'_paradox. it will show the following message:
Axioms:
Hurkens'_paradox relies on an unsafe hierarchy.
Theory:
Type hierarchy is collapsed (logic is inconsistent)

